# Firebase.Auth.PlayGamesAuthProvider class missing in auth 4.4.3?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication, google-play-services

I've been scouring the internet looking to see if anyone else is hitting this problem, maybe some one else here has seen this recently. I'm integrating **Google Play services** and using **Firebase** database with **Google Play authentication** in a **Unity** project.

screenshot of autocomplete list with missing class:

[image: screenshot of autocomplete list with missing class]

For some reason, I seem to **have every component of Firebase.Auth except PlayGamesAuthProvider**, which is needed to call the GetCredential function. I'm seeing this error:

> error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'PlayGamesAuthProvider' does not exist in the namespace 'Firebase.Auth'. Are you missing an assembly reference?

I've reinstalled my Firebase package already and double checked everything for clashing plugins. I'm really hitting a wall here, just curious if anyone else has seen this problem and knows how to get around it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: Sure, but this doesn't seem to be a code issue, at least not an issue related to the code I've written. I'll post a shot of the autocomplete list so you can see what I mean, it looks like all the other namespaces are there (Facebook, Twitter, even regular Google) from the Firebase.Auth class. For some reason just PlayGamesAuthProvider is missing, and this is what Firebase documentation says we should be using for the credentials.

Comment: Can't edit my comment -- sorry not namespaces, I mean classes. PlayGamesAuthProvider should be a class of Firebase.Auth. You can actually see it in the list in their documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/namespace/firebase/auth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone stumbles across this with the same problem, I've got it working. First tried to reimport the latest Firebase.Auth package from Firebase and that didn't fix the problem. I actually tried doing it a second time, making sure that all files were being re-imported, and then also re-imported the latest GooglePlayGamesPlugin package. I'm not sure which fixed it, but there was clearly something breaking down in there, maybe more-so related to the GooglePlayGamesPlugin. I even disabled/renabled my Unity services. Bottom line, keep reinstalling your stuff and eventually it will work. If I notice anything more specific I'll follow up.